# Incorrect syntax near'@ate' c# passing parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

When I execute this code, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '@ate'._, exception unhandled by user

Please help.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{  
    dat = "h1";

    SqlCommand ren = new SqlCommand();
    StringBuilder sbcomand = new StringBuilder("create table @ate (rno varchar, stat bit)");

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ate",dat);
    ren.Parameters.Add(param);
    ren.CommandText = sbcomand.ToString();
    ren.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    ren.Connection = con;

    con.Open();
    ren.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: read the exception fully - not helpful so far... . apart, from that you can also add a try/catch block, preferably with finally to clean up and close the connection.

Comment: Take your SQL and test it independently in SSMS - you'll see its invalid. Also you really want to avoid using string concatenation for executing SQL else you'll make a new friend [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) AKA SQL Injection Attack. If you have to do that sort of dynamic SQL encapsulate it within a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{  
    dat = "h1";
    string sbcomand = string.Format("create table {0} (rno varchar, stat bit)", dat );

    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sbcomand , con))
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```